# bootstrap menu is hiding main text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going crazy with this.  I got the twitter-bootstrap menu running in my c# code and it looks and works great.  However, the menu is overwriting my text of the site I've built.  It seems no matter what I do the body of the site appears under the menu....  I'm thinking it's a CSS issue because if I resize the page to mobile size the body is then placed under the menu.

I'm not even sure what code I should cut and paste...?

I've tried various  or row, ... etc...

How do I get my body text to show below the menu vs. underneath it?

Thanks

Comment: Paste your _layout.cshtml and the typical 'skeleton' of your views :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, I had to do a padding in my `_layout.cshtml`. This solved it for me.

```
<body style="padding-top: 40px;">
```